# cleaning up remains of Datastax Enterprise Hadoop install

Tags: datastax-enterprise

We have removed the analytics datacenter, but I am seeing lots of stuff hanging around.  For instance keyspaces

```
select * from schema_keyspaces;

HiveMetaStore |           True |          org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy |        {"replication_factor":"1"}
```

Also I have references to CFSCompactionStrategy left in the log files.  I want to cleanup our ring completely.  No weird keyspaces ... remove CFSCompactionStrategy Ideas?

Edited with some more info from the recommended solution:

```
UPDATE schema_keyspaces set strategy_options =  '{"Cassandra":"2"}' where keyspace_name in ('keyspace1', 'keyspace2');
drop keyspace cfs_archive;
drop keyspace dse_security;
drop keyspace cfs;
DROP KEYSPACE "HiveMetaStore";
```

Then clean out the folders...

This may be needed as well:

```
DELETE from system.schema_columnfamilies where keyspace_name = 'cfs';
delete from system.schema_columns where keyspace_name in ('cfs', 'cfs_archive');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply drop the HiveMetaStore (and cfs and cfs_archive). The keyspaces are created the first time an analytics node is started and behave exactly like standard Cassandra keyspaces.

At this point you only have the metadata for them; the data shouldn't be replicated on the other nodes unless you changed the replication strategy for those keyspaces at some point.

Comment: CFSCompactionStrategy is still around, but oh well.